# Query repos within organization on GitHub using Github API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I need to assemble script, which will get names of repositories, starting from "test*", within particular organization, on Github.

Can anyone hint me - in which way to dig? Either this possible via some API queries, or I can do this via git command line?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories

Comment: Ok, I use request https://api.github.com/orgs/MYORG/repos?access_token=MYTOKEN&per_page=100 And can list only first 100 repos in this organization. per_page=200 or any other value, greater, than 100 returns only first 100 repos. Can you hint me, which type of request can return repos from 100 to 200? (actually we have 135).

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: https://api.github.com/orgs/MYORG/repos?page=2&per_page=100&access_token=MYTOKEN  works like a charm! Thanks for your help! You can arrange your comments as an answer for this question, if  you want.

Comment: Well, those link-only comments hardly deserve to be answers. If I'd wrote an example script…

Comment: @phd as you wish. But, I think, without your guiding answers, I'l surely didn't find right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembling all answers above I found, that to find all repos (including private) with some search criteria, within organization, I need to use following query:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org:MY_ORG:MY_SEARCHCRITERIA&page=1&per_page=100&access_token=MY_ACCESSTOKEN

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [search query](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) to filter the repository by keyword `test` located in repo name, description or README (but there is no filter for the repo name only) :

#### Github API v3 Rest

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org%3Agithub%20test&per_page=100

#### Github API v4 GraphQL

```graphql
{
  search(query: "test org:github", type: REPOSITORY, first: 100) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22test%20org%3Agithub%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)